# Как выделяется память под объекты в java

Tags: java, heap

В куче выделяется место под объект,хранится ссылка на него, это я понимаю как устроено, а вот при наследовании как это происходит? В начале в куче выделяется место для потомка  и в нем как бы ссылка на родительский или все в одном месте?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к приватным полям класса предка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559431/204271)

Comment: Не "в нем как бы ссылка на родительский", а потомок это и есть "родительский".

Answer (score 0):

[docs.oracle параграф 8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden